# Trying to replace item in list removes the rest of the list

Tags: python-3.x, list

im currently working on a hangman game in python, and this is my code for adding characters to the row of blank spaces.

```
if guess in correct:
  replace = int(correct.index(guess))
  guesslist[:replace] = guess
  print(guesslist)
```

and this sort of works when replacing the very first character.

```
acceptabel
Gissa en bokstav: a
['a', ' _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ ']
```

but whenever i try to replace a character that isnt the first this happens:

```
minus
Gissa en bokstav: n
['n']
```

How do i fix this?

Edit: Full code

```
import random

dead = int(0)
tried = list()
with open("ord.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    words = data.split()
      
    # Generating a random number for word position
    word_pos = random.randint(0, len(words)-1)
    print(words[word_pos])

correct = list(words[word_pos])
guesslist = list()
guesslist.append(' _ ' * len(correct))

guess = input('Gissa en bokstav: ')
if guess in correct:
  replace = int(correct.index(guess))
  guesslist[:replace] = guess
  print(guesslist)
else:
  tried.append(guess)
  print(tried)

if dead == 9:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   0\n|  /|\ \n|  / \ \nL_______')
  print('BRUH HE DEAD')
elif dead == 8:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   0\n|  /|\ \n|  /  \nL_______')
elif dead == 7:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   0\n|  /|\ \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 6:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   0\n|  /| \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 5:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   0\n|  | \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 4:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   0\n|   \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 3:
  print('_____ \n|   |\n|   \n|   \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 2:
  print('_____ \n|   \n|   \n|   \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 1:
  print(' \n|   \n|   \n|   \n|    \nL_______')
elif dead == 0:
  print('\n \n \n \n \n________')
```

Comment: To help clarify your question, You want to insert a new character (guess) into guesslist at the appropriate correct index ,if the character is found within correct?

Comment: Yes, thats what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I would take:
given:

```
correct = 'happily'
answer = [" "]*len(correct)

def update_answer(cor, ans, g):
    if g in cor:
        st = 0
        while st < len(cor):
            indx = cor.find(g, st)
            if indx < 0:
                break
            ans[indx] = g
            st = indx+1
    return ans
```

then
`print(update_answer(correct, answer, "p"))`
Yields:
`[' ', ' ', 'p', 'p', ' ', ' ', ' ']`

To incorporate the above into your code, please excuse the interleaving english, since I am unfamiliar with your native language:

```
import random as rnd

def hangman():
    solved = False
    max_guesses = 4
    good_guesses = 0
    correct = "" 
    tried = []
    # Get new random word
    with open("ord.txt", "r") as file:
        data = file.read()
        words = data.split()
        # Make sure correct is composed of Upper case letters
        correct = rnd.choice(words).upper()
    correct = rnd.choice(test_words).upper()
    answer = [""] * len(correct)  
    while len(tried) < max_guesses and not solved:
        # make sure guess is single letter and upper case
        guess = input('Gissa en bokstav: ')[0].upper()
        if guess in answer or guess in tried:
            print (f"You have already guessed the letter {guess}, try again!") 
    
        elif guess in correct:
            st = 0
            while st < len(correct):
                indx = correct.find(guess, st)
                if indx < 0:
                    break
                answer[indx] = guess
                good_guesses += 1
                st = indx+1
            if len(correct) == good_guesses:
                print('Congratulations You have solved the Puzzle')
                solved = True
                print (f"Answer: {answer} =  {correct}" )
            else:
                print (f'Good Guess\nAnswer Status = {answer}')
       
        else:
            tried.append(guess)
            print (f'Incorrect Guess: {tried}')
            print (f"You have {max_guesses - len(tried)} guesses left")
    if not solved:
        print(f"Sorry you failed to guess {correct}")
```

Comment: Not sure to how to integrate this into my code, ive added my whole program to the question for extra context (right word?) if that helps.